# How to combine two tables to get results from different table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have three tables

[image]

I am **userID: 1231.** I am trying to get results of people who have given me access. I mean their marks with name.

So, according to the tables above I should get results as:

[image]

To fetch the above result I was trying out few queries. One of them is below:

```
 SELECT a.UserID, a.Mark1, a.Mark2, b.Name FROM details a, profile b WHERE a.UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM Access WHERE GrantStatus = 'granted' and GrantUserID = '1231');
```

I get the following results for executing the above query:

[image]

Can somebody help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `join` condition:

```
SELECT d.userID, d.mark1, d.mark2, p.name
FROM details d JOIN
     profile p
     ON d.userID = p.userId
WHERE d.userID IN (SELECT userID
                   FROM access
                   WHERE grantstatus = 'granted' and grantuserID = '1231'
                  );
```

Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

You can do this only with `join`s:

```
SELECT d.userID, d.mark1, d.mark2, p.name
FROM details d JOIN
     profile p
     ON d.userID = p.userId JOIN
     access a
     on a.userId = d.userId
WHERE a.grantstatus = 'granted' and a.grantuserID = '1231';
```

Comment: @`Gordon Linoff` out of curiosity why did you do a sub-select vs another join?

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff I am getting Table 'myDATABASE.userId' doesn't exist

Comment: @TheDevMan . . . There is no expression like that in the query, so I'm a bit confused where it could be coming from.  The query does use table aliases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I fixed it. Can you let me know what is the difference between the two queries? Which one is recommended to be used?

Comment: @TheDevMan At least, the error 'myDATABASE.userId should be about a column (and not a table) that doesn't exist. If a table didn't exist, the error should be something like : 'MyDatabase.Table' doesn't exist..Please read the documentation about [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: @TheDevMan The queries are doing the same job. The first one uses a subquery, the second use a JOIN. There's a slight performance difference between them. The first query must computes first the result of subquery in order to execute the "outer" query. The second (according to me, the best one) query uses a JOIN and its performance is generally better than the first query, especially if the columns involved in the relation are indexed. GordonLinoff, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano: As I have mentioned before. I have fixed the syntax error. I know about Join but didn't understand difference between two queries now that you have explained... Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Thanks this works. Gives me the results properly